# PHP artisan serve shuts down after running once

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4, running php 5.4 and MAMP, and [have cloned this repo](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) but for some reason `php artisan serve` shuts down after running one time (*localhost:8000 runs once, then stops, then I have to use php artisan serve to run it again*). Any ideas to keep it from shutting down?

[Here is where this question originated](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/issues/174#issuecomment-32084989).

Comment: Anything in the PHP error logs after running php artisan serve?

Comment: @Braunson sorry, no errors after running php artisan serve. I've gone through the set up of [andrew13's repo](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site) a few times but no luck. Any ideas? And just a note, this is the only laravel repo I'm having this problem with.

Comment: there is some headway being made at that thread. It seems the error may be narrowed down to Basset as it's no longer being maintained.

Comment: please try using this version https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site/issues/278#issuecomment-32831735

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think I've finally found a solution. In MAMP, try turning off XCache. This solved it for me.

From the MAMP dialog, go to `Preferences->PHP`. Switch the dropdown from XCache to APC.