# Laravel php artisan serve shutting down after running once

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I noticed there was another questions asked like this one but it didn't get any answers. I'm following the Lynda.com course "Up and Running W/ Laravel" and for every example I'm having to run

```
php artisan serve
```

because the artisan server keeps shutting down whenever I go to `http://localhost:8000`. I notice in the video he's just refreshing the page. I've looked online and the most I can come up with is the other unanswered [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058785/php-artisan-serve-shuts-down-after-running-once)
which suggests that something called Basset is the problem. I have no idea what Basset is or why it would be the problem. It suggested switching to grunt but I'm not sure how to start that. I was hoping that it might be a matter of me changing some settings somewhere.  I also saw some comments that said that it might have been an issue with the browser I was using but i tested it on Firefox, Safari and Chrome to the same result.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it definitely has nothing to do with Basset (or Grunt). Those are tools for managing assets (and more) and you would definitely know if you used them...

Comment: create a new fresh laravel project and run your above command to see if it works

Comment: Never resolved the issue. I created fresh laravel project and the same issue persisted. I went with Codeigniter for now. In the future I'll come back to this issue as I really want a framework with ORM capabilities built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Finally found a solution. I assume that you're using MAMP. If so, turn off XCache. It seems to work fine with APC cache.

From MAMP, go to `Preferences->PHP` Change the `Cache` dropdown from XCache to APC.

Comment: Awesome. I will try this when I get back in town and report my findings. Thanks  a lot!